# lxml sourceline returning None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

Need to get line number of xml while parsing it using beautifulsoup and lxml.

The xml is missing root tag so cannot use XML element tree/lxml directly. So scraping it using beautifulsoup. Need to retain filename of xml, the line number, the xml tag and its value in nested dictionaries. Unable to get line number while trying to scrape it using beautifulsoup/lxml. `print(linenum)` returns `None` but needs to return line number in xml file. Any ideas?

```
for xml_file in os.listdir("/Users/abc/Documents/test"):
    mode_map = defaultdict(list)       
    with open("/Users/abc/test/"+xml_file) as raw_resuls:    

        results = BeautifulSoup(raw_resuls, 'lxml')            

        for element in results.find_all("process"):
            attrib = element['mode']                
            if element.find("value") is not None:    
                child = element.find("value").text                    
                linenum= element.find("value").sourceline                    
                print(linenum)                    
                mode_map[attrib].append(child)                    


               # print(mode_map)

        event_map["process"]=mode_map    
        file_map[xml_file]=event_map
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup elements doesn't have an attribute named "sourceline". The reason your `linenum` became `None` instead of raising an `AttributeError` is that BeautifulSoup elements also allow you to find a child by name with a syntax like `element.process` instead of `element.findChild('process')`, with `None` as the failsafe. Personally I don't like this: It might be convenient in many cases, but it feels like sooner or later you will inadvertently bump into an existing attribute of BeautifulSoup elements.

Comment: Since lxml has the feature you want, and BeautifulSoup doesn't, why not directly use lxml anyway? If all that's wrong with the xml is that it "is missing root tag", you can always slap on a root tag yourself, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot find anything better, I am posting this as an answer. Simply `from lxml import etree` like you are used to. Then, do this:

```
    with open("/Users/abc/test/"+xml_file) as fin:    
        raw_xml = fin.read()
        results = etree.XML('<root>' + raw_xml + '</root>')
```

I believe you know what to do next, since you seem to be familiar with lxml. Since the `<root>...</root>` tag pair I added doesn't come with a newline, they should not affect your `sourceline` in any way.

Comment: Thank you! Idea of concatenation of string worked like a charm. However, etree.XML was throwing an error when i tried to parse it, so I looked up the documentation and BytesIO did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me!

```
with open("/Users/abc/Documents/test/"+xml_file) as fin:

        raw_xml = fin.read()

        new_xml="<root>" + raw_xml + "</root>"

        some_file_like = BytesIO(new_xml.encode())

        for event, element in etree.iterparse(some_file_like):
            if element.tag == 'process':
                attrib = element.attrib['mode']
                #print(attrib)
                if element.find("value") is not None:

                    child = element.find("value").text
                    linenum= element.find("value").sourceline
                    print(linenum)
```